# Add Unbreaking Space in BibLaTeX: `\setunit{\addunbreakingspace}`?

Tags: biblatex, spacing, line-breaking

I use `biblatex` for my bibliographies. I have two items at the end, let's call them `Y` and `Z`. (The exact details of what these are is not important.) Currently I separate them with a space via `\setunit{\addspace}`. However, I would like to be able to make this space *unbreaking*. (This is because `Z` is usually only 3 characters long, and so I don't really want that on a line by itself.)

I know how to do this with the usual `~` in text---and using `\usebibmacro{Y}~\usebibmacro{Z}` gives the desired property *when `Z` exists*. But I don't always have access to information `Y` *and* `Z`. The use of `\setunit{\addspace}` only adds the space if `Z` is printed.

Can I make the `\setunit{\addspace}` into an unbreaking space which is only added when `Z` is printed?

Even better, some version of `\nolinebreak[#]` where `#` is a number representing the 'strength' of the request. (I believe that `4`, the maximum, forces no line break.)
I tried `\usebibmacro{Y}\setunit{\addspace}\nolinebreak\usebibmacro{Z}` and `\usebibmacro{Y}\nolinebreak\setunit{\addspace}\usebibmacro{Z}`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` has a variety of space printing commands. They are listed in §4.7.4 *Adding Whitespace* of [the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf). Unbreakable space can be added with `\addnbspace`.

```
\setunit{\addnbspace}%
```

---

For finer control over the line breaks in certain situations `biblatex` has the three commands `\addlowpenspace`, `\addhighpenspace` and `\addabbrvspace`, which are penalised by `lownamepenalty`, `highnamepenalty` and `abbrvpenalty`, respectively.

`\addlowpenspace` and `\addhighpenspace` are intended for typesetting of names/name initials, `\addabbrvspace` for the space in an abbreviation.

---

If none of these float your boat (because they are not the right choice semantically or because you are using them already with a different penalty), it is not too hard to roll your own version if you just copy the implementation of `\addabbrvspace`

```
\newcounter{samtspacepenalty}
% 0 means line breaks after the space are OK,
% 10000 suppresses line breaks after the space
\defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{200}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\addsamtspace}{%
  \unspace\blx@postpunct
  \penalty\value{samtspacepenalty}\space
  \blx@imc@resetpunctfont}
\makeatother
```

With the standard classes we'd have the following correspondences

```
\nolinebreak[0] -> \defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{0}
\nolinebreak[1] -> \defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{51}
\nolinebreak[2] -> \defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{151}
\nolinebreak[3] -> \defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{301}
\nolinebreak[4] -> \defcounter{samtspacepenalty}{10000}
```

Comment: in theory `\setunit{~}` would work as well, but `\setunit{\addnbspace}` does additional house keeping and can avoid some unwanted double space, so it is in general to be preferred over `\setunit{~}`

Comment: That's awesome, thank you! Sorry that the main answer was just in the documentation. I probably should have found that... I shall have a read of the documentation -- although your answers on here tend to be more understandable to me than the docs!

Comment: @SamT Well, it's a well known shortcoming of the `biblatex` docs that they are basically only a reference manual, which often means that you have to know the answer to the question before you can find something about it in the docs. So don't worry about asking about stuff that turns out to be documented somewhere in the manual. If you can't find it, chances are other people will also have a hard time finding it, so the question may help others.